# Programmatically extracting .deb packages

Tags: c++, c, linux, package, deb

I have `.deb` package whose contents I need to extract in a programmatic way. However, I am not able to find any resources on the topic, such as `.deb` package format specification, which would give me some more idea how to approach the problem without going and reverse engineering the whole thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't find a library for this (I didn't, either), and cannot resort to running system commands, you can always implement your own to read ar archives.  The [ar file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) isn't terribly complicated.

Comment: The wiki page I linked to above gives enough details to write your own library to extract the files.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple, actually.

```
ar xv <name of deb file>
```

To call from within C, you could use `system`:

```
system("ar xv <name of deb file>");
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the design goals for the `.deb` package format was to make it easy to extract using existing tools and/or libraries.  The top-level structure is indeed an `ar` file, but inside that, you will find another level of structure, which is traditionally a pair of `tar` files.  For more documentation, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)

You can probably use the GNU `ar` sources to build a library of your own if you cannot find an existing library.  I would expect there to be general libraries for ar / tar / cpio / what have you.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw [libarchive](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/) supports the `ar` format, along with a ton of others.